# html.dropdown is not retaining selected value

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I can successfully fill out my form and submit data to the database.  However, if the model fails validation, the drop downs on the form do not show the selected value.

I can see in the html that the value of the dropdown input is correct -- but the value isn't being displayed to the user.  How do I get the dropdown to display the value?

Example:

HTML renders:

```
<select class="field panel-field" id="TempAvailability_0__AvailabilityMinimumHours"     name="TempAvailability[0].AvailabilityMinimumHours" value="36"><option value=""></option>
<option value="40">40</option>
<option value="39">39</option>
<option value="38">38</option>
<option value="37">37</option>
<option value="36">36</option>
<option value="35">35</option>
</select>
```

View:

```
string AvailabilityMinimumHours = "";
if(Model != null)
{
    AvailabilityMinimumHours = Model.AvailabilityMinimumHours.ToString();
}
 @Html.DropDownList("TempAvailability[0].AvailabilityMinimumHours", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)this.ViewBag.HoursList, new { @class = "field panel-field", @value=AvailabilityMinimumHours })
```

Displays as:

[image: minhours]

Comment: What value has AvailabilityMinimunHours after been set from model view?

Comment: In the example above, 36.  My model has the correct value, which is why I can save to the database correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally.  After days of hair pulling, I've figured this out.  The key was to set the selected value in the controller, where the select list is built.

I had to change the controller by passing in the value, and then setting selected on the list when it's built.

```
        private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetHoursList(byte? hour)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> hoursList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var selected = false;
        hoursList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "", Text = "" });
        for (int i = 40; i >= 5; --i)
        {
            if (hour == i)
            {
                selected = true;
            }
            hoursList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString(), Selected = selected });
            selected = false;
        }
        return hoursList;
    }

        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowAvailability(Availability availability)
    {
        this.ViewBag.HoursList = this.GetHoursList(availability.AvailabilityMinimumHours);
        return PartialView("_AvailabilityPartial", availability);
    }
```